# Temporary Mount 2nd Windows data Drive

Tags: windows, mount, drive

I have a Windows 7 system which has just had a Motherboard Failure. The System had 4 Hard drives. 1 With OS, the Others with only DATA. I want to temporarily mount the data drives so that I can copy current working data to an alternate drive?

Can Anybody please help?  Other wise I will have to buy a new windows machine to re-install the drives on th enew system just to copy the data off the drives??

I am Running Ubuntu 12.04 at the moment.

Thank you

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 2):

After the drive is attached to the computer (either the ide/sata cable or an usb ide/sata adpator) run this command to look for the partition:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
```

Pick out the partition with the data and mount it with:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/[partition to mount] /[mount folder]
```

(Replace [partition to mount] with your windows data partition name shown by the previous cat command.  Replace the [mount folder] with the folder specified for the mount.)

example:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
```

By the way, you can also get the list of partitions with:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

Comment: solved my biggest problem